# Convert julian day into date

Tags: python, bash, awk, julian-date

I have files named day00000.nc, day00001.nc, day00002.nc, ...day00364.nc for several years.
They represent the 365 or 366  days.
I want to rename my files like this day20070101.nc, day20070102.nc , ...day20071231.nc
How can I do that ? 
Thank you

Comment: Where is your year being represented?

Comment: Are they all in the same year? What is the starting date point?

Comment: @Franko - not all in the same year.  I would guess they all have mtimes or ctimes which correspond the the %j in the filename, so datetime will handle it using stat input.

Comment: This question doesn't actually have anything to do with Julian dates... You just want to parse normal dates.

Answer (score 15):

Use the [datetime](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) module to get date from day of the year. I am assuming the year is 2007 as in your examples, since your filenames do not seem to have an year value. Feel free to replace the hardcoded `2007` in the code with a variable if required.

```
import datetime
oldFilename = 'day00364.nc'
day = int(oldFilename[3:-3])
date = datetime.datetime(2007, 1, 1) + datetime.timedelta(day) #This assumes that the year is 2007
newFilename = 'day%s.nc'%date.strftime('%Y%m%d')
print newFilename # prints day20071231.nc
```

**For those who are downvoting this answer because "this solution adds a day"**

The OP's files are numbered 0 to 364, not 1 to 365. This solution works for the OP. In case your dates are from 1 to 365, and it's not at all obvious to you, please freel free to subtract "1" from the day variable before converting it to a timedelta value.

Comment: I think you need to change `strptime` to `strftime` on the last line.

Comment: @Aya Thanks for catching that!

Comment: I think this adds a day.

Comment: @seaotternerd For you and others who are down-voting, please see my edit.

Comment: @Dhara - I didn't actually down-vote (I upvoted, because your answer deals well with the actual question and fixing off-by-one errors is pretty trivial), but thanks for the edit!

Answer (score 3):

`datetime` has a build in julian converter in it's `strptime` function using the `%j` format specifier.  Assuming that your files are `'day'` two digit year + julian + extention (if not, just add whatever year offset you really have)

```
file_date = filename[3:-3]
file_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(file_date, '%y%j').strftime('%Y%m%d')
new_filename = file_date.strftime('day%Y%m%d.nc')
```

after comment about how to get the year

```
year = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getctime(filename)).year
file_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(filename[5:-3], '%j').replace(year=year)
new_filename = file_date.strftime('day%Y%m%d.nc')
```

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk and any Bourne-like shell

```
for old in *
do
    new=$( gawk -v old="$old" 'BEGIN{
            secs = (gensub(/[^[:digit:]]/,"","g",old) + 1) * 24 * 60 * 60
            print gensub(/[[:digit:]]+/,strftime("%Y%m%d",secs),"",old)
        }' )
    echo mv "$old" "$new"
done
```

Remove the "echo" after testing.