# Parse string into date with wildcards or dateutil.parser

Tags: python, datetime, parsing

I have a series of string that I am trying to parse into dates. They are of the form (001 is the julian day)

```
code_36763.letters_81m_2013_001_0000.dat
```

Only that the numbers which don't compose the date change, so in wildcards this would be

```
code_?????.letters_??m_%Y_%j_%H%M.dat
```

My first thought nwas to try this is `datetime.datetime.strptime`, but I get an error saying that `ValueError: time data does not match format`, which means that `strptime`does not understand wildcards. Then my second thought as to use `dateutil.parser`, but when I do

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
f='code_36763.letters_81m_2013_001_0000.dat'
parse(f, fuzzy=True)
```

I get the error

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

which probably means that those other numbers are getting in the way.

Is there a way to solve this without manually cutting the other numbers? I ask this because the code I have to write should be general enough that the other numbers can be in different positions along the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this could work by using `re.sub` to reformat the file name into something that `strptime` could parse.

```
>>> import re
>>> import datetime
>>> filenames = ["code_36763.letters_81m_2013_001_0000.dat", "code_36763.letters_81m_2013_240_1700.dat"]
>>> for n in filenames:
...   parsed = re.sub(r"code_\d+.letters_\d{2}m_(\d{4})_(\d{3})_(\d{2})(\d{2}).dat", r"\1-\2-\4:\3", n)
...   print datetime.datetime.strptime(parsed, "%Y-%j-%H:%M")
...
2013-01-01 00:00:00
2013-08-28 00:17:00
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a regular expression:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.match(
        r"code_\d{5}.letters_\d{2}m_(?P<year>\d{4})_(?P<day>\d{3})_(?P<hour>\d{2})(?P<minute>\d{2}).dat", 
        "code_36763.letters_81m_2013_001_0000.dat"
    ).groupdict()
{'year': '2013', 'day': '001', 'minute': '00', 'hour': '00'}
```

You can then convert the numbers to integers and pass them on accordingly. See e.g. [Convert julian day into date](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17216169/3001761) for help with that step.

Answer (score 0):

The string as you have it appears to be fairly fixed format. If this is the case, then the following approach might suffice which simply slices off the beginning so that it is suitable for `strptime`:

```
import datetime

filename = "code_36763.letters_81m_2013_001_0000.dat"
print datetime.datetime.strptime(filename[-19:-4], "m_%Y_%j_%H%M")
```

Giving you the output:

```
2013-01-01 00:00:00
```